# Which glue to use to repair a tent outer?

Tags: tents, repairs

In strong wind (and bad tent placement) on the top of a hill, one of my tent poles snapped. I've subsequently replaced it. But the snapped pole has put a hole though one of the pole guides on the tent outer. My tent comes with a "repair" kit including scrapes of material to fix the outer but no glue.

what glue should I use?

The tent is a Vango Cyclone 200+ from about 2010. The outer is laminated nylon I guess though it doesn't say. I'm wary of using a glue that will melt the plastic fibres but I also want one that will seal the hole quite securely as it will need to resist the tent pole pushing though the hole when erecting.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SilNet Seam Sealer is designed to seal the seams on nylon flysheets and can also be used glue to repair the same. See http://www.terra-nova.co.uk/tents-and-spares/all-tent-accessories/seam-sealer-glue/ for more information.

Alternatively, you could get Vango to repair the flysheet for you: http://www.vango.co.uk/gb/content/28-aftersales

Comment: Nota: SilNet is for silicon-coated fabrics only. For PU, use seam grip.